# Dual norm of a max function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, inequalities, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization

I am attempting to find the dual norm of 
$$\|(x,y)\|_K=\max\{|x|,|y|,|x-y|\}.$$
I have obtained $\|(x',y')\|_K^* = |x'|+|y'|$, but don't think that this is correct.
I obtained this as follows :
$$K = \{(x,y)\in R^n : \max\{|x|,|y|,|x-y|\} \leq 1\}$$
$$|(x,y).(x',y')| = |xx' + yy'| \leq |x||x'|+|y||y'| \leq \max\{|x-y|,|x|,|y|\}(|x'|+|y'|) \leq |x'|+|y'|,$$
thus concluding that $\|(x',y')\|_K^* = |x'| + |y'|$.
I don't think that this is correct because I know that this is the dual norm of $\max\{|x|,|y|\}$.  What is the correct dual norm?

Comment: You are essentially looking at the norm of a subspace $P$ of $\ell^\infty$ (its a plane inside the 3-dimensional space with the max-norm $\ell^3_\infty$). If you have a look at the section on duals of quotients in Rudin, you will see, that the dual of a subspace is (isomorphic to) the a quotient, here $\ell^3_1 / P^\perp$ (with the quotient norm). It should be a nice exercise for you to figure out exactly, what this gives.

Answer (score 2):

The dual norm of $(a,b)$ is $|a|\vee|b|\vee|a+b|$, where $A\vee B\vee\cdots:=\max(A,B,\dots)$.

---

**Details:**

The dual norm of $(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2$ is 
$$m=m_1\vee m_2, \tag{1}
$$
where 
$$m_1:=\max\{ax+by\colon-1\le x\le 1,0\le y\le 1,-1\le x-y\le 1\} \\ 
=\max\{ax+by\colon0\le y\le 1,y-1\le x\le 1\}, 
$$
$$m_2:=\max\{ax+by\colon-1\le x\le 1,-1\le y\le 0,-1\le x-y\le 1\} \\ 
=\max\{ax+by\colon-1\le y\le 0,-1\le x\le 1+y\}.  
$$
Further, by the linearity of $ax+by$ in $(x,y)$, 
$$m_1=\max\{a(y-1)+by\colon0\le y\le 1\}\vee 
\max\{a+by\colon0\le y\le 1\} \\
=(-a)\vee b\vee a\vee(a+b). \tag{2}
$$
Similarly, 
$$m_2=(-a-b)\vee(-a)\vee a\vee(-b). \tag{3}
$$
So, by (1)--(3), indeed $m=|a|\vee|b|\vee|a+b|$.

---

Another way to compute the dual norm $m$ of $(a,b)$ is to note that $m$, equal the maximum of the linear form $ax+by$ over all points $(x,y)$ in the unit ball $K$, is the maximum of $ax+by$ over all the extreme points of $K$, which are $(-1,-1),(0,-1),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1),(-1,0)$. Here is the picture of the ball $K$:

[image]

So, 
$$m=(-a-b)\vee(-b)\vee a\vee(a+b)\vee b\vee(-a)=|a|\vee|b|\vee|a+b|. 
$$

Comment: What is a good reference for this and norms?

Comment: @VS. : I am not good at references. Try keywords such "normed spaces",  "linear programming", "convex analysis", "extreme points".